# Collect images url and data from webpage table to Excel table

Tags: vba, excel

Need to collect data from table on a webpage, some table cell have images.
  The codes is to copy the data to Excel, and if the cell has images, then get its src links instead of images. below are the codes, but it is not working, I don't know how to detect if the cell has image in it or not, and add its src links to Excel cell.

```
Sub extractData()

Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim myYear As String
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
Dim elemCollection As Object



Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")



myYear = InputBox("Enter year")

With IE

.Visible = True
.navigate ("url")


While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend


For Each obj In IE.Document.All.Item("Year").Options

If obj.innerText = myYear Then

obj.Selected = True

End If

Next obj



IE.Document.getElementsByName("btn_search").Item.Click

Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K2000").ClearContents



Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")



For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 9)

For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText = "" Then

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).getAttribute("src")
Exit For
End If
Next

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
Next c
Next r
Next t

End With


Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, brush up on [HTML Document Object Model](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). There are tons of tutorials on how to use JavaScript to work with the DOM, and VBA is real similar (because the DOM doesn't change based on language and VBA is very closely related to VBScript which is similar to JavaScript). Second, if you get an error but no line is highlighted when you click the Debug button, step through your code line by line with the F8 key. This will let you figure out where the error is occurring. Third, add a reference to the `Microsoft HTML Object Library` so you can use Intellisense for code hints.

It's tough to give an actual solution without seeing the HTML source so instead I'll give some pointers:

Use `IE.Document.Body.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")` (note the addition of `BODY` to narrow the scope) to get a collection of every table on the page. With a reference to the HTML Objects Lib you can do something like this:

```
Dim oTable As HTMLTable
Dim oCell As HTMLTableCell
Dim oImg As HTMLImage
Dim strSrc As String
For Each oCell In oTable.Cells
    strSrc = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oImg = oCell.getElementsByTagName("img")
    strSrc = oImg.Source
    On Error GoTo 0
    If strSrc <> "" Then Debug.Print strSrc
Next
```

This should (I did not test it) loop through every cell in a table and attempt to get an img element. If it fails, no biggie, just continue to the next cell. If you want to use late binding after you get it working, remove the HTML Obj Lib reference then simply dim everything as an object. Eg:

```
Dim oTable As Object 'HTMLTable
Dim oCell As Object 'HTMLTableCell
Dim oImg As Object 'HTMLImage
Dim strSrc As String
```

Comment: Set elemCollection =IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")  
    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 9)    
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
    For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)            
    If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText <> "" Then            
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).getAttribute("src")  Else ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText    End If     Next c  Next r
    Next t  End With  Set IE = Nothing  End Sub

Comment: but nothing show up, no bugs, i think it is something wrong with this :                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).getAttribute("src")

Comment: What do you want to do with the src once you have it? If all you want is the text of the link, then just load the entire HTML document into a string (`strDoc = IE.Document.Body.InnerHTML`) and look for all the instances of `src="/marksix/info/images/icon/no_` using `instr`. If you actually want the HTML elements because you need to work with the HTML elements (and not just a string), simply loop through the [`Document.Images` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) looking for src attributes containing `icon/no_`.

Comment: You just need to find a unique attribute that makes the data you want different from the data you don't. Once you find that, simply figure out the easiest way to get that data. IMO, selecting tables, looping through tds, and then checking src attributes is not the easiest way to get the images you want.